# search pattern from one file in another file and writing the line after the match into a third file

Tags: search, awk, grep

I want to search the content of one file into another file and print the matched line and line that followed the matched line from the second file. The content of the first file can be found in the lines starting with `>` under `GN` column in the second file. I want to write the line that matches (starting with `>`) followed by the line after that which has the sequence of amino acid ( string of capital letters starting with **"M"**)

File 1:

```
thrB
yaaX
thrC
dnaK
dnaJ
```

File 2:

```
>sp|B1XBC8|KHSE_ECODH Homoserine kinase OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12 / DH10B) OX=316385 GN=thrB PE=3 SV=1
MVKVYAPASSANMSVGFDVLGAAVTPVDGALLGDVVTVEAAETFSLNNLGRFADKLPSEP
>sp|P0AD61|KPYK1_ECOLI Pyruvate kinase I OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) OX=83333 GN=pykF PE=1 SV=1
MKKTKIVCTIGPKTESEEMLAKMLDAGMNVMRLNFSHGDYAEHGQRIQNLRNVMSKTGKT
>sp|P75616|YAAX_ECOLI Uncharacterized protein YaaX OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) OX=83333 GN=yaaX PE=3 SV=1
MKKMQSIVLALSLVLVAPMAAQAAEITLVPSVKLQIGDRDNRGYYWDGGHWRDHGWWKQH
```

and i am expecting output as:

```
>sp|B1XBC8|KHSE_ECODH Homoserine kinase OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12 / DH10B) OX=316385 GN=thrB PE=3 SV=1
MVKVYAPASSANMSVGFDVLGAAVTPVDGALLGDVVTVEAAETFSLNNLGRFADKLPSEP
>sp|P75616|YAAX_ECOLI Uncharacterized protein YaaX OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) OX=83333 GN=yaaX PE=3 SV=1
MKKMQSIVLALSLVLVAPMAAQAAEITLVPSVKLQIGDRDNRGYYWDGGHWRDHGWWKQH
```

so far I have tried 
`grep -F -f file1 file2`
which only prints the line with the match found

with awk I only have written
`awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{} file1 file2` 
I can print the matching line but I don't know how to print the line after that (starting with "M").

Can anyone help me in getting through this?

I would be really grateful for your help.

Also, what if my second file has multiple matches of the string in file 1 and I want to print all such occurrences?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `GNU grep`

```
grep --no-group-separator -A1 -Ff file1 file2
```

- `-A1` will tell grep to print the matching line as well as the next line
- by default, the output groups will be separated by `--`, so use `--no-group-separator` if you wish to avoid this line

Comment: thanks it worked.

How about if I want to print all the lines after `>` until it encounters another `>` and the number of lines in between are varying say 4 or 5 or 6?

Comment: @codeblaze sorry for the late reply... something like `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} /^>/{f=0; for(k in a) if($0 ~ k) f=1} f' file1 file2` may work (haven't tested it)... if I'm correct in guessing that this is bioinformatics related, I'd suggest that https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ would suit you better

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/GN=[^ ]*/){
  str=substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)
}
(str in a) && /^>/{
  found=1
  val=$0
  next
}
found && /^M/{
  print val ORS $0
}
{
  val=found=""
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two files are in fasta format, you should rather try **blastn** from the **blast+** suite of tools, which is optimized in performance and will give you extra information on the pairwise alignment (identity rate, length of the overlap, number of missmatches and gaps)

```
blastn -query file1 -subject file2 -oufmt 6 > outfile.csv
```

And then parse the result if you want the output as a third fasta file.